# How can I add 1 to many relationship for these two tables in mysql each customer has at least one pet

Tags: mysql

how can i add 1 to many relation for these two tables each customer has at least one pet

```
create table customer (
id int primary key,

cname varchar(15),

address varchar(15) ,

phone1 integer (15)

);

create table pet (

pname varchar(15),

color varchar(15),

weight int

);
```

Comment: can the pet have more than one owner?

Comment: no, the pet can have just one owner

Comment: then add simply a column to the pet table that has the owners name. but when the name is not unique you will get into trouble. So you should add a promary if field that works as relation ship to the pet table

Comment: @hamzehm2003 Does your tables have primary keys? And to be clear: a customer must have at least one pet? It is not possible that you have a customer without a pet?